# How to convert time that is in float datatype to HH:MM:SS date format

Tags: python, date, format

I am trying to retrieve a time  from excel that gets save as 0.65693287037 instead of 21:53:00. Is there any logic to covert it into normal time format.

Comment: An Excel time is usually just a fractional number of days, so you can just do `datetime.timedelta(days= 0.65693287037 )` and then add that to midnight. But if that's the case, the time would be 15:45:59, not 21:53:00, so… something is weird. Being 6 hours off because of mixing up local and UTF time is plausible, but being 6 hours, 7 minutes, and 1 second off?

Comment: I tried With a different value i was able to get the original time. Thanks